# How to avoid bcprov-jdk16-1.45.jar while running the application through POM entry

Tags: java, itext, bouncycastle

I have a Java 8 application running in Weblogic 12.1.3. The application uses iText 5.5.9 and minimum version of BC  required is 1.49 . The application is deploying as a WAR file in Weblogic . I could see the war file is having the proper version of BC . But during run time its taking from WebLogic maven plugin path and using BC 1.45. Is there any way we can avoid this by editing POM entry or by editing WebLogic.xml . If i remove BC 1.45 jar from my local server its running successfully. But i cannot remove the jar from higher environment server . So Please help. Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful were you to excerpt the relevant section of the POM and include it in your answer, formatting it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem. BC broke their API in-between versions, and when you have two different BC versions in your CLASSPATH, you can get very strange errors (which might differ depending on which version was loaded first). I see that you're still using the old iText (not iText 7), which means you can switch to iTextG.

The G in iTextG stands for Google, and iTextG was created to avoid some problems. For instance:

- Java classes that aren't whitelisted for use on GAE or Android were removed,
- Specific file operations that don't make sense in a cloud context were adapted,
- Bouncycastle was replaced with SpongyCastle.

BouncyCastle and SpongyCastle are identical, except for their package names and the name of the security provider ("BC" versus "SC"). Because of these differences, two different versions, such as version 1.45 of BC in WebLogic and version 1.49 of SpongyCastle in your iTextG application won't clash.

This was necessary for use of iText on Android, because Android shipped with an old version of BC (just like your WebLogic ships with an old version).

Comment: Not only the package name is changed between BC and SC, the security provider name also is. And this is important to allow iTextG to access SpongyCastle! This also implies that after replacing iText by iTextG the OP additionally has to register SC as security provider.

Comment: OK , But there is no way we can edit POM to make sure the BC jar file will be always from lib not from web-logic server ?

Comment: But what about those tags in  POM like <scope>provided</scope> and in weblogic XML  <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes> . Why these are not taking any effect after build

Comment: Modified the code according to Bruno Lowagie and its working fine now . Thanks .